# Exchange Distribution Lists - How to name?

Tags: exchange

Folks - what naming conventions are used in your organization when creating DLs in the GAL?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently we use the following conventions.  They sort very nice in the GAL.

For system Alerts

- alert.xxx
- alert.yyy

For inter department communications

- team.tech
- team.delivery

We have the generics that are exposed to the outside world

- netops
- accounting
- abuse
- security

For service accounts

- svc_sql_cluster
- svc_ops_mgr

For locations or offices

- CompanyHQ
- CompanySFO
- CompanyRemoties
- CompanyDallas

Comment: Thomas, thanks for the answer.  Why do you have system alerts and service accounts in the GAL or are they hidden?

Comment: They are all hidden from the GAL, but I wanted to expand further what system has worked for me over and over.

Answer (score 1):

I like to start with a prefix of some sort so they sort nicely in the GAL perhaps '_GRP'.  Then I try and work from the least specific to the most specific.

- _GRP_Administration
- _GRP_Fiscal
- _GRP_IT
- _GRP_IT_Operations
- _GRP_IT_Web

Comment: We do the prefix too gr_ops-project-dev (for dev) and gr_ops-project (for users) often gr_logs-project too